# How to put UIGestureRecognizer in front if several views with gestures overlaps

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I have two views that have tap gesture recognizers attached. The first view accepts touches while the second one is hidden. After some time, I'm making the second (with attached gesture) view visible. The problem is that, still, only the touches of the first view are handled, despite the second view is in front :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, forgot to put "user interaction enabled". I'm drawing my views and other stuff with interface builder, therefore I have missed that :)